# How to move one cursor only in multi-cursor mode in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, atom-editor

In Sublime Text 3, to the best of my knowledge, when **using keyboard only**, you can only control all cursors simultaneously after you have created them, which is not very handy when, say, I want to move the latest created cursor only to some designated location.

Atom's [multi-cursor](https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor) package allows you to only move the latest cursor that you have created.

So I wonder if there is a native method to do this in Sublime Text 3 or if there is a package similar to Atom's [multi-cursor](https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor) that allows you to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed all of the built in commands that change the caret location (e.g. `move`, `move_to`) operate over all of the current selections at once, so natively there is no way to perform an operation such as this without writing a plugin that alters the selections individually.

I'm not familiar with Atom (or that package), but the [MultiEditUtils](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MultiEditUtils) or [PowerCursors](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PowerCursors) packages may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I need! Thanks!